AWS fargate with EcsRunTaskOperator
In my last job,
i was on GCP and we launched services as API with fastAPI on cloud run.
When airflow dag called the cloud run service, it raise it with a 10 minute timeout and i can use the same service over and over.
The problem with ECS tasks is i need to call X times the tasks for each API call in my DAG. Because when the call is success, the service shutdown.
I don't want an ECS service as i don't use my API 24/24 but only for few calls.
Do you have any ideas how could i workaround this issue ?

You could use autoscaling on a schedule and put the min/max number of tasks for the ECS service to 0? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/ec2-auto-scaling-scheduled-scaling.html

Thank you this is a very good idea.

Not sure if that is an option in your case, but why not use a Lambda function instead?

Because of execution time, industrialization and maintainability.

If you're moving from Cloud Run's convenient setup to AWS, I'd recommend AWS App Runner. It's the closest match - scales to zero and handles concurrent requests like Cloud Run does.
If you need to stick with ECS, you could use a Lambda as a "manager" that keeps your ECS task alive for a time window (say 30 mins) after the first request. This way multiple DAG calls can reuse the same task instead of spawning new ones. When the window expires with no activity, let it shut down naturally. This gives you the on-demand behavior you want without the overhead of constant task creation.
